Make typescript check `this` in free functions
I can't get Typescript recognise the error in the following code:
function foo() {
    console.log(this.x.y)
}

foo()

When I execute it with npx ts-node a.ts, it does not exhibit any typescript errors, but naturally fails with
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'y')

Is there any way to make Typescript recognise that there is no this.x in this code so that it will be Typescript compilation error, not a runtime error?
My ts-config.json is (it might well be not ideal):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2022",
  },
  "include": ["/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "files": ["a.ts"]
}

I'm using Node 18.13.0, typescript 5.2.2, ts-node 10.9.1 (the latter two installed via npm).

That is indeed a type error with the default config, on that Typescript version. See playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIgxCBAZzgBsBTAOnLgHM0oALGE6gD2oE8NcBfXLhToMQA. Do you see this error in your editor? Are you asking how to ensure that ts-node won't run your file if there are type errors?

@AlexWayne, interesting, thanks. My VS Code does not show the error, as well as ts-node, while both show other errors. So most probably something with my config...

Googling by the error message from the playground, I found the relevant setting in tsconfig: "noImplicitThis": true

I've found that generating this error is governed by noImplicitThis setting in tsconfig.json's compilerOptions. Setting
noImplicitThis: true

makes Typescript report the error:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
a.ts:2:17 - error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

2     console.log(this.x.y)

UPD: Following a comment from @AlexWayne, there is a more general setting:
strict: true

It also makes Typescript report this error.

Note that this will default to true if strict is true. And that enables lots of over best practices. So that's probably what you want.
